# Azure Ad B2C Profile Edit Can't Delete Claim

Tags: azure-ad-b2c, identity-experience-framework

I am running into an issue where my users login to the Profile Edit page and delete the values for some of the claims that are not required.

For example...

If the Claim giveName had a value of "Test" and the user deleted it the value would now be "" or string.empty.

However, when the journey is completed the RP is still passing the original value "Test" back to the application and also not persisting the "" empty string to Azure AD.

Here are the relevant technical profiles:

```
<TechnicalProfile Id="UpdateConsumerInformation">
          <DisplayName>Business Information</DisplayName>
          <Protocol Name="Proprietary" Handler="Web.TPEngine.Providers.SelfAssertedAttributeProvider, Web.TPEngine, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null" />
          <Metadata>
            <Item Key="ContentDefinitionReferenceId">api.selfasserted.profileupdate</Item>
            <Item Key="language.button_continue">Continue</Item>
          </Metadata>
          <InputClaims>
            <InputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="givenName" />
            <InputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="surName" />
            <InputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="extension_Company" />
            <InputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="streetAddress" />
            <InputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="extension_streetAddress2" />
            <InputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="city" />
            <InputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="state" />
            <InputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="postalCode" />
            <InputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="country" />
            <InputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="extension_Company" />
            <InputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="extension_Phone" />
            <InputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="extension_Consent" />
          </InputClaims>
          <OutputClaims>
            <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="givenName" Required="true" />
            <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="surName" Required="true" />
            <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="extension_Company" Required="false" />
            <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="streetAddress" />
            <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="extension_streetAddress2" />
            <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="city" />
            <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="state" />
            <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="postalCode" />
            <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="country" Required="true" />
            <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="extension_Phone" />
            <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="extension_Consent" Required="true" />
          </OutputClaims>
          <ValidationTechnicalProfiles>
            <ValidationTechnicalProfile ReferenceId="WriteConsumerInformation" />
          </ValidationTechnicalProfiles>
        </TechnicalProfile>
        <TechnicalProfile Id="WriteConsumerInformation">
          <DisplayName>Customer Information</DisplayName>
          <Metadata>
            <Item Key="Operation">Write</Item>
            <Item Key="RaiseErrorIfClaimsPrincipalAlreadyExists">false</Item>
          </Metadata>
          <IncludeInSso>false</IncludeInSso>
          <InputClaimsTransformations>
            <InputClaimsTransformation ReferenceId="CreateDisplayNameFromFirstNameAndLastName" />
          </InputClaimsTransformations>
          <InputClaims>
            <InputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="signInName" PartnerClaimType="signInNames.emailAddress" Required="true" />
          </InputClaims>
          <PersistedClaims>
            <PersistedClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="signInName" PartnerClaimType="signInNames.emailAddress" />
            <PersistedClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="displayName" DefaultValue="unknown" />
            <PersistedClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="givenName" />
            <PersistedClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="surName" />
            <PersistedClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="streetAddress" />
            <PersistedClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="extension_streetAddress2" />
            <PersistedClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="city" />
            <PersistedClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="state" />
            <PersistedClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="postalCode" />
            <PersistedClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="country" />
            <PersistedClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="extension_Consent" />
            <PersistedClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="extension_Company" />
            <PersistedClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="extension_Phone" />
          </PersistedClaims>
          <IncludeTechnicalProfile ReferenceId="AAD-Common" />
        </TechnicalProfile>
```

What I would expect is that if a user were to clear the contents of one of the claims, that the claim would be cleared in azure ad b2c and the RP would not return the original value.

Comment: Have you tried with non empty strings? Are those persisted? Can you share your full RP and base policies files?

Comment: Hi Alfredo, yes non empty strings do persist.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `AllowGenerationOfClaimsWithNullValues` metadata item in the "UpdateConsumerInformation" TechnicalProfile.

```
<TechnicalProfile Id="UpdateConsumerInformation">
          ...
          <Metadata>
            <Item Key="AllowGenerationOfClaimsWithNullValues">true</Item>
            <Item Key="ContentDefinitionReferenceId">api.selfasserted.profileupdate</Item>
            <Item Key="language.button_continue">Continue</Item>
          </Metadata>
          <InputClaims>
            ...
          </InputClaims>
          <OutputClaims>
            ...
          </OutputClaims>
    <ValidationTechnicalProfiles>
        <ValidationTechnicalProfile ReferenceId="WriteConsumerInformation" />
    </ValidationTechnicalProfiles>
</TechnicalProfile>
```